grails 6.2 cannot resolve views in some versions of tomcat
Using Open jdk 11.0.2 and grails 6.2.
The latest (and last) version of tomcat 8(8.5.100) runs fine.
An earlier version of tomcat 9 ran ok.
The latest version of tomcat 9(9.0.89) cannot load any of the assets or views. An example of the error thrown is ....
/catalog/list  [Could not resolve view with name 'list' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet']

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'list' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1385)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)

Notice that the error message is slightly different than usual; The directory "catalog" is missing. In a working version, if I trigger the same kind of error with a missing view it says
/catalog/resolvetest  [Could not resolve view with name '/catalog/resolvetest' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet]

However, even views which have the full path or are in the top level directory do not resolve
 /error  [Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet]

I'm hoping there is a simple configuration/setup change that will help.
